# Issue with setting an image on a UITableCellView (using AFNetworking) just before reloading a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, restkit, afnetworking

In my app I populate a UITableView with entities from CoreData and right after than make a server request to check if there are new entities (which are added to the table view with `reloadData`).

In the first rendering of the cell, each cell sets an image using AFNetworking `setImageWithURL` method (as a note, AFNetworking is included in the project as part of RestKit).

The problem occurs once I call `reloadData` before the images are loaded. Reloading the data causes the cells to request for the images once again, and I also get in the log these errors:

```
restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:175 GET <MY-PHOTO-URL> (0) [14.1694 s]: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" {NSErrorFailingURLKey=<MY-PHOTO-URL>}
```

In addition to the error, I also get logs that the images finished loading with status 200, but none of the table's cells have the images.

Of course if I disable the data reloading the images are loaded perfectly so the problem is with `reloadData`.

Comment: For this type of image usage I like to use HJCache (https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache) as it deals well with cancellation of the request (image view removed from screen) and prevents repeated download of the images (I know AF does too but HJ gives more control I think).

Comment: it was last updated 2 years ago though. Does it support ARC?

Comment: It doesn't, but it isn't a complex conversion or you can compile it without ARC. There are also a number of forks. Or I can send you a version if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, no need though :) I'll look around